# Backward propagation of error in FIR Neural Networks

Tags: finite-impulse-response, machine-learning, system-identification

**FIR Networks** are a really great kind of Neural Networks. It allows very precise **predictions** of missing samples for example when ones wants to reconstruct missing signals or adaptive noise cancellations, etc

I'd like to understand **how they work** and a great paper about it is the one by **WAN in 1993** : http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/publications/ps/wan93c.pdf

here is an **example** of a FIR connection, and the computation of the **weight changes** knowing weights $b()$ or $a()$, inputs $u(k)$, $x(k)$ and error $e(k)$
[image]

It is said in the paper that : as the signal has to be ***propagated*** through the network, the resulting error has to be ***back-propagated*** through the same network

here is a simple image explanation

[image]

so **the goal is to find** $\delta$(k) for a given neuron to be able to work backwards the gradient (the error)

here is the formula of the weights ($a()$, $b()$) updates:
$$\bigtriangleup  \bf w \rm ^l _{ij} = - \mu \delta^{l+1} _j (k) \cdot \bf a\rm^l_i(k) \ \ (1)$$

where

$$\delta^l_j(k) = -2e_j(k)f'(s^L_j(k)) \ \ (2)\normalsize \\\ if \ l = L \ (last \ layer) $$
and 
$$\delta^l_j(k) = f'(s^l_j(k))\cdot\sum_m \bf\delta\rm ^{l+1}_m(k)\cdot\bf w\rm ^{l+1}_{jm} \ \ (3) \normalsize \\\ if \ 1 \leq l \leq L -1$$

$f'$ is the derivate of the activation function. An important point is that $\bf w \rm ^l _{ij}$ and $\bf \delta$ are ***vectors***, not scalars.

page 26 we see : 
$$\bf w\rm^l_{ij} = [ w^l_{i,j}(0), w^l_{i,j}(1), \ ... \ ,w^l_{i,j}(M^l)]$$

and the vector of delayed activation values is :
$$ \bf a\rm ^l _i (k) = [a^l_i(k), a^l_i(k-1), \ ... \ , a^l_i(k - M^{l+1})]$$

**So let's take the first step** : it is the last layer L (filter b in this example) and we have the error $y(k) = e(k)$, the actual weights $b(0), b(1), b(2)$ and the signal values $\bf a\rm^l_i(k) = [u(k), u(k-1) ...]$

I'm trying to understand fully how to compute each weight change.

using (2) we first compute the weight change 
$$\bigtriangleup w_{b(2)} = - \mu \delta^{l+1} _j (k) \cdot \bf a\rm^l_i(k)$$
$$\bigtriangleup w_{b(2)} = 2 \mu e_j(k)f'(s^L_j(k)) \cdot u(k-2)$$

so we have the new weight

$$b(2) = b(2) + \bigtriangleup w$$

**is this first assertion correct?**

and if it is, i have trouble understanding what is the next step:

1. do we have to multiply $e(k)$ by the new weigth $b(2)$ to get the error for the next backward step (at weight $b(1)$) ?
   so for b(1) we use $$\bigtriangleup w_{b(1)} = 2 \mu e_j(k)b(2)f'(s^L_j(k)) \cdot u(k-1)$$
2. or do we have to use always the same value of e(k) for the next weight update : $b(1) = b(1) - \mu \delta^l_j(k) \cdot u(k-1)$ ?

***for the second FIR filter*** there is a difference.
Here we use eq (3) as **it is not the last layer L.**

in this simple case of two cascaded FIR filters, i think $(1)$ could be rewrote as:

$$\bigtriangleup  \bf w \rm ^l  = - \mu \delta^{L} (k) \cdot \bf x\rm(k)$$

where $\delta^{L} _j (k)$ is the previously calculated $\delta$ and $x(k) = [x(k), x(k-1), \ ... \ , x(k-M)]$
and as before we multiply the gradient $\delta$ by the updated weights and go backward to the start.

**is it right?** or am i wrong (and where)?

Also it would be very nice if ones could possibly put some general pseudo-code to compute the whole FIR network or point to some existing code so i can compare the algorithms.

**Thanks for help**

Jeff

Comment: Can you please make the text and TeX formatting consistent, i.e. remove any `\huge` markups? It looks awfully terrible and is impossible to read. Can you imagine reading a book written like that?

Comment: sorry i removed the \huge. are you able to help me now?